# Bash script: Using sed to stream a Environment variable to a file

Tags: git, bash, sed

I am using the `sed` command in a bash script to stream a `COMMIT_SHA` value into a python file. Before running this bash script, the settings.py file has this line:

```
COMMIT_SHA = ""
```

After the bash script it needs to have the actual commit sha like so:

```
COMMIT_SHA = "56e05fced214c44a37759efa2dfc25a65d8ae98d"
```

Doing this in python would be easy, but I need to use Bash to get this done. The following is the approach I've tried:

```
COMMIT_SHA=`git rev-parse HEAD`
sed $PROJECT_DIR/settings.py "^COMMIT_SHA = .*$" 'COMMIT_SHA = "$COMMIT_SHA"'
```

However this simply puts `COMMIT_SHA = "$COMMIT_SHA"` into my settings.py which isn't what I want.

Comment: It might be a little easier if you make your initial file say `COMMIT_SHA = "PLACEHOLDER"`. Then you can just `sed -i -e "s/PLACEHOLDER/$(git rev-parse HEAD)/" settings.py`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have enclosed the final line in `''`s.

Instead, try

```
sed $PROJECT_DIR/settings.py "^COMMIT_SHA = .*$" "COMMIT_SHA = \"$COMMIT_SHA\""
```

or, in the more normal form

```
sed -i "s/^COMMIT_SHA = .*$/COMMIT_SHA = \"$COMMIT_SHA\"/" $PROJECT_DIR/settings.py
```